# Swift 3 upload Video to server

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to upload a video to my server.  I can currently upload images fine but when trying to upload a video I have no clue on how to approach this.  I currently use the following for uploading images:

at "let image" Throws a error when I select a video from the album.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{

    let imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
    let image             = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
    let data              = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Comment: If you took a video, why are you trying to get an image?

Answer (score 8):

here , we have upload video using Alamofire library, follow below steps so you can easy uploaded video.
Step 1. :-  add extension and pick the video

```
extension UploadStatusViewController : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as? String {

            if mediaType == "public.movie" {
                print("Video Selected")
                let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL

                selectedVideoURL = videoURL
                self.playVideo(videoURL)
            }
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Step 2. :- and add Alamofire library and set this method

```
func callAPIForUploadVideo{

        ShowLoaderOnView()
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            // code
// here you can upload only mp4 video
                multipartFormData.append(self.selectedVideoURL!, withName: "File1", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
// here you can upload any type of video            
                //multipartFormData.append(self.selectedVideoURL!, withName: "File1")
                 multipartFormData.append(("VIDEO".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false))!, withName: "Type")

        }, to: /* Set Url Here */ , encodingCompletion: { (result) in
            // code
            switch result {
            case .success(request: let upload, streamingFromDisk: _, streamFileURL: _):
                upload.validate().responseJSON {
                    response in
                    HideLoaderOnView()
                    if response.result.isFailure {
                        debugPrint(response)
                    } else {
                        let result = response.value as! NSDictionary
                        print(result)
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                HideLoaderOnView()
                NSLog((encodingError as NSError).localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can we do it with URLSession? i don't want to include a dependency in my project

Comment: append(("VIDEO".data(using...etc
like what is "video" string? url? phasset?av? what?

Comment: @OmarNShamali  this is a string parameter nothing else, it other parameter for type of media. (ignore that parameter.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alamofire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for uploading and downloading of file

Please check below examples of **alamofire** for uploading file

**Example 1**: Uploading Data

```
let imageData = UIPNGRepresentation(image)!

Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

**Example 2**: Uploading a File

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")

Alamofire.upload(fileURL, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

**Example 3:** Uploading Multipart Form Data

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")
    },
    to: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: How can we do the same without Alamofire?

Comment: Can we do it with URLSession? i don't want to include a dependency in my project